# When only caring for several algorithms relative performance, would I be better off forcing Java to never JIT compile my methods?

Tags: java, performance, profiling, measurement

When comparing two different algorithm implementations (thus, not caring for their absolute, but only relative performance) am I better off forcing Java to only run interpreted code?

That is, would I be better off with the `-Xint` flag on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you'd be better disabling JIT.

Either you decide to measure the abstract, asymptotical performance (and in this case you definitely want the big-O notation), or you decide to measure the performance of a given implementation on a given machine for given input data.

If you decide to go for the latter, then it would be pointless to disable JIT: what you want is to measure performance in a realistic environment, and in a realistic environment you'd generally have JIT compilation.

Answer (score 1):

From a theoretical standpoint, yes, that should guarantee that you'll get accurate results about how efficient one is compared to the other. And if one takes much less time, the result is pretty obvious.

However, it's possible in some cases (though I don't think very likely) that the algorithm you thought was slower will be more suited to JITing, and it will be faster when Java is allowed to optimize it.

The usual way to measure performance in Java is to let it "warm up" first - run the algorithm a few times (see -XX:CompileThreshold) first to get it to compile, and then time it.

Answer (score 1):

Both.

If you are performing a benchmark, you want to have information of which environment settings affect performance.

You may not be able to run your algorithms with all the computer configurations available, but seeing the effect of turning on/off JIT should be considered.

Comment: Why exactly would I want to profile with a setting I'm **never** going to actually run in production? Seems completely pointless to me...

Answer (score 1):

the question is...will you be disabling JIT in production as well...the art in performance analysis is ensuring you are indeed measuring the same very thing (model) that you are trying to observer, understand and optimize.

if you want to compare algorithms without actually profiling their behavior under realistic conditions (load, env, state,...) then you could use the tried and tested method of creating a cost table for each execution cost driver and then summing those costs across executions (or walkthroughs) of the test.